# Llightroom strange lens default correction profile with Canon 17-40 f/4L

Tags: canon, lightroom

When using Lightroom Classic I have discovered that the default lens correction profile used for a Canon 17-44 f/4L lens looks a bit strange compared to other lenses in my collection.

By default the Profile says "Canon EOS-1D Mark III (Canon EF 17-40mm f/4L USM"

This seems strange because

1. The lens profile refers to a camera (Canon EOS-1D M3) and not just
   the lens
2. The camera it refers to is not mine, nor have I ever even
   touched this model!
3. It is different to other default profiles which just refer to the lens, as I would expect (it is lens correction)

See the screenshot

[image: Screenshot len profile problem]
I can change this to another profile "Adobe (Canon EF 17-40mm f/4L USM)", which is the one I expect by default.  But it seems strange to have to do that here, when I don't with other lenses.

For example, below is a screenshot from the default for another lens.
[image: 70-200 lens]

Here, there is only this single profile available.
And it is the same for all the other lenses I have tried.  It is only the 17-40 which seems to have the issue.

Although I can't spot any difference in the profiles, it is strange.

Does anybody know what the problem is and how I can resolve it?

Comment: What camera is it? A 1D mk3?

Comment: Do you mean which camera did I use to take the photos?  A Canon 80D and the same also occurs when another user uses a Canon 77D with the same lens, and uses lightroom on a different PC (different subscription).

Comment: I noticed yesterday that a photo I had taken a couple of days ago with my Canon 5D Mk IV and Canon 17-40 f/4 of Lake Michigan had a warped horizon (raised slightly in the center). I just figured the lens profile correction in Lightroom wasn't completely accurate. After seeing your question I went and looked and indeed I had the same problem you describe. After changing it to the Adobe one, the horizon is now straight! So there's definitely an issue with it there somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While this could be a Lightroom Classic bug, there is a way to "fix" it.

In the **Develop Module**, go to **Lens Corrections**, change the lens profile to **Adobe (Canon EF 17-40mm f/4 L USM)**, then select **Save New lens profile defaults** from the **Setup combobox** located below the **Enable Profile Corrections** checkbox. Newly imported photos taken with that lens should now default to that.

Comment: Follow-up: Adobe is now aware of this "bug" and is going to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is a separate profile is because prior to the 1D X series, Canon's 1D series were 1.3X APS-H cameras that had a different field of view from either their full frame 1Ds and 5D series or their APS-C 1.6X crop bodies when using the same lens(es). Adobe should more properly label it something such as [EF 17-40mm f/4 L (1.3X APS-H)].

While Adobe products seem to natively adjust lens profiles for the difference between FF and APS-C cameras, there doesn't seem to be any automatic (unseen to the end user) provision to do so with images from APS-H camera bodies. Thus the end user is given the option to do it manually. As to why Adobe seems to identify your EOS 80D and 77D bodies as 1.3X APS-H instead of 1.6X APS-C when using this one particular lens, only Adobe can answer that. My guess is that there is a bug in the Adobe code for that lens' correction profile that has never been brought to Adobe's attention.